# dynamically populating a drop down based on selection of one dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to populate one drop down based on selection of another drop down . I am using struts framework and used jquery to solve the above problem statement . my code is getting stuck at the point where it makes a GET call to the server using .json() method .Can someone help me on this .

my jquery code :

```
<div id="Symptoms" style="display:none;">
<html:form id="iamhere" method="POST" action="symptoms" >
<p></p>
<p>Enter/Choose ailment : 

<select id="diselc" name="AuthoringForm"  size="1" >
<option selected="selected"> </option>
<option>Malaria</option>
<option>High Fever</option>
<option>Cholera</option>
<option>Diarrhoea</option>
</select></p>
<p>Choose ailment classification : 
<select id="diselchild" name="AuthoringForm" > 
<option>High</option>
<option>Medium</option>
<option>Low</option> 
</select> 



<fieldset style="width: 381px; height: 126px; padding: 2">
<legend align="left"></legend>
 Tick off patient context :
<html:radio value="Men" name="AuthoringForm" property="patient_context" disabled="false"/>
Men
<html:radio value="Womwen" name="AuthoringForm" property="patient_context" disabled="false"/>
Women
<p>
<html:radio value="Child" name="AuthoringForm" property="patient_context" disabled="false"/>
Child
<html:radio value="Al" name="AuthoringForm" property="patient_context" disabled="false"/>
All
</fieldset>
<p>Enter Pre Conditions</p>
<p><html:textarea rows="2" name="AuthoringForm" cols="20" property="patient_precondition" ></html:textarea>
<p>Must Have Symptoms : 
May Have Symptoms :</p>
<p><html:textarea rows="2" name="AuthoringForm" cols="20" property="must_have_symptoms"></html:textarea>
<!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B2">-->
<html:textarea rows="2" name="AuthoringForm" cols="20" property="may_have_symptoms"></html:textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="symptomsButton"><input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clear_form_elements(this.form);"></p>
</html:form>
</div>
```

My jquery:

```
<script> 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                $("#diselc").change(function(){ 
                    fillOptions('diselc','diselchild'); 
                    }); 
            }); 
            function fillOptions(parentId,ddId) {
                alert("atleast the call is being made in the fillOptions"+ddId);
                var dd = $('#' + ddId); 
                alert("the value being passed is "+dd);
                var jsonURL = 'http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/decisiontreeAction.do?dd=' + ddId + '&val=' + $('#' + parentId + ' :selected').val(); 
                $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(opts)
                {
                alert("just after calling the servlet stuff ");
                    $('>option', dd).remove(); // Clean old options first. 
                    if (opts) { 
                        $.each(opts, function(key, value) { 
                            dd.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value)); 
                        }); 
                    } else { 
                        dd.append($('<option/>').text("Please select parent")); 
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
 </script>
```

Can someone help me on that .

Comment: what error do you get in the firebug console

Comment: its not giving any error but my "alert("just after calling the servlet stuff ");" is not coming up .

Comment: can you see the ajax call initiating ? in the firebug console ?

Comment: yeah first two alerts came up

Comment: try this `var jsonURL = '/docRuleTool/decisiontreeAction.do?dd=' + ddId + '&val=' + $('#' + parentId + ' :selected').val();` make sure you are specifying correct url. P.S. are you familiar with firebug console if yes then see in its `Net` panel under `jxhr` whether the request is made or not and if not then google the term and follow the steps `:)`

Comment: actually i am using developer tool from google chrome to debug the javascript ... is there any tool of this sort in google chrome.

Comment: In the Firebug console, look at the xhr request: Make sure that your request URL is correct. Paste the URL in the browser to make sure you get the right result. You can of course look at the response in Firebug too.

Comment: Maybe try hooking into the `error` or `complete` jqXHR events to see what's being returned? According to the jQuery docs, JSON calls will fail silently. Also, as @3nigma said, does the XHR call and return show the right values in Firebug? Edit: Typing too slowly. Sorry guys...

Comment: ok my bad i should have mentioned in chrome hit `f12` it will bring up dev tools then look  in the network tab

Comment: @bhalkian Chrome has this too (I prefer it actually): hit Ctrl-Shift-I to bring up the dev tools, then the network tab will show XHR. The Scripts tab will allow you to insert breakpoints and the like so you can examine the page state too.

Comment: @meloncholy excellent point make it an answer with an example of how to sepcify error call back  with `$.getJSON` it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @meloncholy make an error callback

```
$.getJSON(jsonURL, function() {
 //your code here
  alert("success");
})
.error(function(jxhr) { alert(jxhr.ResponseText); });
```

see if the error handler gets called...

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I obviously need to post replies more quickly. :)

Comment: @meloncholy i waited for you to answer but then i made a reference `:)`